# Debugging asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm new to web development, so sorry for noob question.

I running VS 2013 with asp.net mvc 4. Each time when I starting debugging of application (F5), new tab being added to web browser (chrome). So, after half hour of development I find myself with dozens of open tabs.

Is there any more comfortable solution? I don't know, maybe some way to close tab when debugging is stopped.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you stop debugging? Go to VS Debug-> Stop Debugging?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets: after stopping debugging, there is still left open tab in browser. Many start/stop debugging produces tons of open tabs. this was my question - how to avoid this

Comment: Instead of going to VS and pressing "Stop Debugging" you can close tab, this will automatically stop debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of "Attach To IIS" when you want to debug and not open any more tabs in Chrome.

[image: Image of Attach To IIS]

Comment: For some reason I can't find "Attach to IIS" button. Which toolbar contains it? Also, it is not clear for me how this going to solve my problem, since I developing against development server (asp_dev or something).

Comment: Oh.. Seems this is a feature of the plugin VSCommands. You could always locate the right process and attach to it via Tools -> Attach to Process. Attach to IIS shows you all open IIS instances (including development-IIS's)